# Dynamic bar width of d3 bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart

I've an array of objects like this one

```
[{
    "frequency": 1,
    "position": 20
}, {
    "frequency": 2,
    "position": 60
}, {
    "frequency": 3,
    "position": 100
}]
```

Setting the yAxes is easy

```
var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
    return d.frequency;
  })])
  .range([0, chartHeight]);
```

But I don't know how to calculate the x position and width of the bars. I can do it manually when iterating over every records and calculating the `width` by subtracting the next record and the current one, and set the `offset` from the `position` parameter, but there is the case with keeping the bars in the `chartWidth`, so I want to do it using the d3 methods.

Comment: Use an ordinal scale (or a band scale in the new D3 4.x). The best idea is creating a fiddle or a plunkr, with your manually calculated width, so we can easily change for an ordinal scale and show you the code.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Here is the [code](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/50988/), I use an ordinal scale, but I don't know how to get the position in. My idea is for every element to subtract it's value from the next one using the position value and this way to calculate the desired width.

Comment: I looked at your code and, before talking about code, we have to talk about dataviz: your data have only "frequency" and "position". Who goes in the y-axis and who goes in the x?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado frequency goes into the yScale so it is for y-axis. The problem is the x and how to make the bars a different width depending on the position, so lets say for the first bar if we have 20 for the position and 60 for the next, I want it to be width a relative width of 40 and get it somehow in the xScale if possible.

Comment: The width of the rectangles will be positionOfNextElement - positionOfCurrentElelment and position 0 will be just the first bar(rectangle).

Comment: Ok, so this *is not* a bar chart. Moving on: you have a position 0, so the first rectangle will be plot at the origin, is that right? Ans what will be the width of the last rectangle? To make things worse, your data have these positions: `[0, 80, 19]`... 19 is less than 80!

Comment: Sorry about the 19, it should be 190, my mistake when moving the code from json to a js array.

Comment: What about the width of the last bar?

Comment: Maybe it can be given some default value, I don't care much about it.

Comment: If it's easier I can change the position parameter to width and calculate it on the back end, so we can have it ready for use.

Comment: I believe it's the best option. Right now, in your code D3 methods are useless because there is no data bound to DOM elements.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118701/discussion-between-lexx-and-gerardo-furtado).